# geometrical interpretation of cokernel

Tags: linear-algebra, vector-spaces

i would like to understand geometrical interpretation of Cokernel,from Wikipedia it is defined  by the following way

```
cokernel (plural cokernels)
(category theory) The dual object of a kernel
```

i dont understand if  it is related to  linear algebra as well,because in linear algebra kernel is  set of vector   $v$ for given matrix $A$, for which

$Av=0$

also we know that dual space ,for example dual vector space takes   input as a vector and produce scalars,so according to these two definition,what does Cokernel in vector space?if it takes  vector and produce scalar,then how above equation will change?thanks in advance

Answer (score 10, accepted):

In general,
the cokernal of a homomorphism $f:X\to Y$ of algebraic objects is defined to be
$Y$ mod the image of $f$. In the case of a linear transformation given by a matrix
$A:R^n\to R^m$, you can use the dot product in $R^m$ to identify $R^m/{\rm image\,}(A)$ with the orthogonal complement of the image. But this becomes more down to earth as follows: a vector $y$ is in $({\rm image\,}(A))^\perp$ when
$y\cdot Ax=0$ for every vector $x$ in $R^n$.  But $y\cdot Ax = (A^Ty)\cdot x$, and this is zero for all $x$ only when $A^Ty=0$. Equivalently $y^TA=0$.

Short version: kernel of $A$ is all $x$ with $Ax=0$, and cokernel of $A$ is all $y$ with $y^TA=0$.